Asymptotic Conditional Likelihood Ratios of Two Models
Suppose that $X_t$ is distributed i.i.d. across time ($t=1,2,3,...$) and takes values in $\{0,1,2\}$. Suppose that for each $x\in\{0,1,2\}$ the true probability that $X_t = x$ is given by $p_x$, for some $(p_0,p_1,p_2)\in (0,1)^3$ s.t. $p_0+p_1+p_2 = 1$.
Now, suppose that there are two models, which are precisely defined as follows. Each model $i\in\{1,2\}$ specifies

A parameter space $[0,1]$.
For each parameter $c \in [0,1]$, a probability triple $\vec{q}_i(c) = (q_{i0}(c),q_{i1}(c),q_{i2}(c))$, which is assumed continuous in $c$.
A prior distribution over parameter $c$ with p.d.f, $r_i(\cdot)$. Assume that $r_i$ has full support on $[0,1]$, is continuous, and bounded.

Furthermore, suppose that for each model $i\in\{1,2\}$, $\exists c_i^*\in[0,1]$ s.t. $(q_{i0}(c_i^*),q_{i1}(c_i^*),q_{i2}(c_i^*)) = (p_0,p_1,p_2)$. That is, each model has a parameter value such that it specifies the objectively correct probability triple.
My question is as follows: I am trying to characterize the asymptotics of the conditional likelihood ratio (CLR) of these models. Specifically, I define the CLR as follows: for each $T\in\{1,2,..\}$ and each $x\in\{0,1,2\}$, let $N_{xT} \equiv\sum_{t=1}^T \mathbf{1}_{\{x\}}(X_{t})$ count the number of $x$ draws by time $T$. Then the CLR is given by
$$
\lambda_T = \frac{\int_{0}^1 q_{10}(c)^{N_{0T}} q_{11}(c)^{N_{1T}} q_{12}(c)^{N_{2T}} r_1(c)  dc }{ \int_{0}^1 q_{20}(c)^{N_{0T}} q_{21}(c)^{N_{1T}} q_{22}(c)^{N_{2T}} r_2(c)  dc }
$$
My intuition tells me that this will converge almost surely (or in probability) to $r_1(c_1^*)/r_2(c_2^*)$. That is, the ratio of the prior densities of the parameter for which each model specifies the correct probability triple.
The main challenge for me is how to deal with the integrals here. Any guidance on this would be very much appreciated. If any additional "niceness" conditions are needed on $q$ or $r$ please let me know.
